# Can molecules used in double slit experiments interact with light?

Tags: photons, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality, molecules

If a photon hits a molecule while it's in a wave state will it collapse it into a particle?

Comment: This question could benefit from more details: are you talking about a two-slit experiment performed on molecules? Or on electrons? Or photons? In the latter two cases, where do the moecules come from - the screen (and what if it is metallic?) or the experiment is in a gas?

Comment: I am taking about a two slit experiment performed on molecules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

While passing through the slit both light and molecules will be in the "waves state", so they will behave the same way as two beams of different wavelengths - so they will create overlapping interference patterns.

Answer (score 0):

First some clarification, when the wave function collapses it just collapses, typically the energy that was in the EM field gets transferred to the material/atom/molecule.

In the double slit experiment when NO interference is observed physicists like to say that the wave function collapsed and the photon is acting like a particle .... this is incorrect and misleading ... but is a common mis-understanding unforetunatley.  All particles always wave properties, if you mess with the particle after the slits it changes it original wave properties, the geometry of the slit has no more effect.

When buckey balls or other matter is passed thru slits we get the mysterious pattern, it seems impossible matter could "interfere".  To understand this experiment we go to Feynman and Dirac who said every photon decides its own path (there are no photons in the dark areas of the pattern)... and we can apply this to matter .... no interference.  SO how are these particles choosing paths (bright areas) and not others (dark areas) in the pattern.  Feynman proposed the path integral theory for light to explain it (you can search some of my responses on this site).  Fundamentally all interactions of matter involve the EM field, to accelerate very small particles strong voltages are used to get them thru the double slit to the screen.  Before the molecule has even left from its starting position the EM field works virtually thru virtual photons, preferred probable paths per Feynman are more often traveled resulting in the pattern.